# multisite custom directory

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I have a multisite installation with domain mapping 
at the original site I was changed the wp directories to a custom

- wp-content changed to {root}
- themes moved to {root/themes}
- plugins moved to {root/ext}
- uploads moved to {root/uploads}

Every thing is working great on the main site.
On the mapped sites it works with uploads and themes even the plugins show up and I can activate and deactivate plugins and manage them.
But look like there is a problem in the plugins dir because the plugins don't show as it should be (I mean css)

Now this is my wp-config edits

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '');
    define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', ABSPATH . '/ext' );
    define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/ext' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . '' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '' );
    define( 'UPLOADS', ''.'uploads' );

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

There is something wrong I think in the `ABSPATH` or  `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

But I don't know what it is.

Note that themes and uploads are working well, plugins work but not as they should.

Answer (score -1):

Add this:

```
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', ABSPATH . '/ext' );
```

Comment: Why should that help? That's an arbitrary constant, nothing more.